# i am not able to call or assign textBox.text from within another method

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0, path-finding

I am trying to display the results of my app in the listbox or textbox but neither is working. i don't know how to call the `textBox1.Text`

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //listBox1.Items.Add(printPath());
}

private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

I want to print the values from this method:

```
static void showPath(List<PathFinderNode> mPath)
{
    TextBox tx = new TextBox();
    ListBox ls = new ListBox();
    var bn = new ListBox();
    string disP = "nnnn";
    MessageBox.Show("show path reached"); //method check
    try
    {
        foreach (PathFinderNode node in mPath)
        {
            if ((node.X - node.PX) > 0) { disP = "Right"; }
            if ((node.X - node.PX) < 0) { disP = "Left"; }
            if ((node.Y - node.PY) > 0) { disP = "UP"; }
            if ((node.Y - node.PY) < 0) { disP = "Down"; }

            ls.Items.Add(disP);
            tx.Text = disP;
            bn.Text = disP;
        }
    }
    catch (FormatException p)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(p.Message);
    }
}
```

and yes, I get the message that says "show path reached" so I know the program reaches that point. just the display isn't working.

Comment: There could be another exception that's occurring but not being caught because you are only catching FormatException; which is a good start but maybe step through and look for another exception that is firing.

Comment: You are creating new TextBoxes and new ListBoxes and never adding those controls to a form.  You are probably trying to reference existing controls.

Comment: A control to be visible should be added to its form controls container. Your code creates three controls, change the content of these controls and then nothing else happens. You need to add the controls on the form window with _formInstance.Controls.AddRange(new Controls[] {ls, tx, bn})_

Comment: I think you need not use the local variables `tx` & `ls` but rather the instance variables `textBox1` and `listbox1`.

Comment: Is “the listbox or textbox” already in your form? Then you need to assign to the existing controls already on your form, not create new ones and then throw them away without displaying them. Or do you intend to create new controls that didn't exist before? Then you need to add them to your form (that takes a lot more work than just `new ListBox()`).

Comment: yes, the textBox and listBox are already in the form. I don't need new textbox i was trying to reference textBox1 but it doesnt't allow me to use textbox1 in the showPath method

Comment: i have changed it to this and still nothing on the display.Form1 fm = new Form1 ();
                  fm.listBox1.Items.Add(disP);
                    fm.textBox1.Text = disP;

Answer (score 0):

Why not make the method just return the path steps and let the caller decide how to handle it.

```
static string[] showPath(List<PathFinderNode> mPath)
{
    List<string> paths = new List<string>();
    string disP = string.Empty;
    MessageBox.Show("show path reached"); //method check
    try
    {
        foreach (PathFinderNode node in mPath)
        {
            if ((node.X - node.PX) > 0) { disP = "Right"; }
            if ((node.X - node.PX) < 0) { disP = "Left"; }
            if ((node.Y - node.PY) > 0) { disP = "UP"; }
            if ((node.Y - node.PY) < 0) { disP = "Down"; }

            paths.Add(disP);
        }
    }
    catch (FormatException p)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(p.Message);
    }
    return paths.ToArray();
}
```

Then you can just call it like so:

```
listBox1.AddRange(showPath(...));
```

Comment: thanks! i"ll try this. i sorta abandoned that part of the project.